# Running out of memory when mapping a function to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ram

I've recently developed a function to convert a list of strings that look something like this (these strings are 101 characters long in my case):

`['AGT', 'AAT']`

To a numpy array, like so:

```
array([[[[1],
         [0],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [1],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [0],
         [0],
         [1]]],

       [[[1],
         [0],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[1],
         [0],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [0],
         [1],
         [0]]]])
```

The shape of which is `[2, 3, 4, 1]` in this case.

```
def sequence_list_encoder(sequence_list):

    import numpy as np
    mapping = {
        "A": (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        "G": (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        "C": (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        "T": (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
        "X": (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
        "N": (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        }

    bits = [b for seq in sequence_list for ch in seq for b in mapping[ch]]
    
    one_hot_encoded_array = np.fromiter(bits, dtype=np.uint8)
    one_hot_encoded_array.shape = (len(sequence_list), len(sequence_list[0]), 6, 1)
    print(one_hot_encoded_array.shape)
    
    return one_hot_encoded_array
```

Although this works fine for the most part (a practice list of 1.6 million sequences of 101 characters (A,C,G,T,N,X). My ultimate goal is to use this on containing 91 million of 101 character sequences. Although this file is 2.4gb, running this function is using over 124 gb RAM (my available memory).

Is there a realistic way to get around this without using more RAM? For instance, simultaneously writing to an output .npy file as the function maps to the data? Or using different data structures?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Why don't you use sparse matrices?

Comment: I admit I've never come across them before! looking at scipy.sparse suggests they're two dimensional?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but in any case the idea is to save space by not storing all the zeros

Comment: Also why don't store the lists as 3 dimensional arrays, is the last dimension always going to be 1?

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions! I think your idea of not storing the zeros is great, I'll try and implement that! The last dimension is always going to be one - I Believe it's needed in a downstream process, despite being a placeholder here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that python does not let you make true bool arrays. Thus by saving ones and zeros as `unit8` you are using 8 times more space than you think you are. To fix this you can encode every sequence of 6 bits as an actual number. Numpy has a built in function for this called `packbits`. I have converted your code such that it uses this encoding function and a decoding function when you actually want to read the answer.

```
import numpy as np

ls =['AGT', 'AAT']

def sequence_list_encoder(sequence_list):
    mapping = {
        "A": (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        "G": (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
        "C": (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        "T": (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
        "X": (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
        "N": (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
        }
    #init the result array. Notice its 6 times smaller than the old one
    res = np.zeros((len(sequence_list), len(sequence_list[0])), dtype= np.uint8)
    #go line by line through the input to never make large copies
    for i, seq in enumerate(sequence_list):
        #convert into list of chars
        char_list = list(seq)
        #map the mapping
        full_map = map(lambda x: mapping[x], char_list)
        #encode the bit sequence in a single uint8
        encoded = map(lambda x: np.packbits(np.array(x, dtype = bool)), full_map)
        #paste it into the result
        res[i,:] = np.fromiter(encoded, dtype=np.uint8)
    
    return res

def decode_line(arr):
    #unpack the compressed bits to the mapping
    return np.unpackbits(arr)[:6]


example = sequence_list_encoder(ls)
print(example.size * example.itemsize)
for i in range(3):
    print(decode_line(example[0,i]))
```

As presented this code will use the same amount of memory for the input and for the output. If this still does not fit in RAM then you should consider breaking up your data set into smaller chunks.